# Double Gerund Agreement

Tags: gerunds

> Training and improving these skills **yield/yields** better decision-making and fewer mistakes during a game.

Training and improving - it should be 'yield' but 'yields' sounds better - can someone help on this? Which is grammatically correct?

Comment: It depends on if you're using the term to describe a single, collective action or two separate actions.

Comment: There is a single thing that is yielded. Thus yield is singular. The outcome is a single outcome, not multiple outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

A subject consisting of multiple gerunds may take a singular verb when they may be construed as a single action or sequence. If the writer sees them as different actions, then a plural verb is chosen. Compare these five pairs in which the first sentence uses a singular verb and the second a plural one:

> For many of us, [*baking and eating*](https://www.craftcompany.co.uk/blog/index.php/alternative-christmas-cake-ideas/) a traditional fruity Christmas cake is one of the best parts of the festive holiday. — Alternative Christmas Cake Ideas | The Craft Company Blog
>
> [*Baking and eating*](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/631418810231052515/) are part of what makes the holidays so special for a lot of people. — Pinterest
>
> The [*mowing and raking*](https://books.google.de/books?id=dPHa2EVhvQIC&q=%22mowing+and+raking%22+lawn&dq=%22mowing+and+raking%22+lawn&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0wIuo3bHfAhXFDuwKHbhTCvE4ChDoAQg6MAQ) of these crops requires 25 to 100 per cent more time than mowing and raking alfalfa. — Waldo Ernest Grimes, *A Study of Farm Organization in Central Kansas*, 1925, 41.
>
> While [*mowing and raking*](https://www.portageturf.com/blog/3-steps-to-prepare-your-ohio-lawn-for-winter/) are easily done by most homeowners, aeration and fertilization are generally best left up to trained professionals. — Portage Turf Specialists, 29 Oct. 2016.
>
> [*Reading the book and then watching the movie*](https://barbershopbooks.org/family-literacy-month/) is an engaging way to keep your young reader reading. — Family Literacy Month – Barbershop Books
>
> *Cuckoo's Nest* is the rare case where I think both [*reading the book and watching the movie*](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1847233-has-anyone-read-the-book-and-watched-the-movie) are important. — Goodreads.
>
> Only after [*the painting and sculpting*](https://www.loislambertgallery.com/miguel-millo/) is completed, a process that takes several hours, does Milló photograph his models. — Miguel Millo — Lois Lambert Gallery
>
> [*Painting and sculpting*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Cg9UWNOnSiwC&pg=PA53&dq=%22Painting+and+sculpting+were%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOppnX3bHfAhWL_aQKHWJEBy4Q6AEIKjAB) were not part of the liberal arts, which included philosophy, grammar, dialectic, mathematics, and astronomy. — Ian P. Howard, Brian J. Rogers, *Perceiving in Depth, Volume 1: Basic Mechanisms*, 2012, 53.
>
> [*Speaking, reading and writing*](http://tutorbright.com/tutoring-ottawa/esl/) English is perfected only through practice … ESL - TutorBright
>
> The answer is that [*writing and speaking*](https://books.google.de/books?id=wVJ-ii-R2sUC&pg=PA92&dq=%22Writing+and+speaking+are%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT_dTH3rHfAhXJsaQKHTOaC7UQ6AEIJTAA) are social behaviors, performed by human beings, in stressful environments, and that, quite often, our models of correct rhetoric are just biologically inadequate.  — David F Beer, *Writing and Speaking in the Technology Professions: A Practical Guide*, 2003.